# extracting a variable's value from text file using bash

Tags: bash

I am using Linux and bash.
I have a simple text file like below:

```
VAR1=100
VAR2=5
VAR3=0
VAR4=99
```

I want to extract by means of bash the value of VAR2, that is 5.

How could I do that?

Comment: Use `grep` and `cut`

Comment: Or just use `awk` with `=` as the field split character.

Comment: Or `source simple_text_file; echo $VAR2`.

Comment: Or `sed -n 's/^VAR2=\([0-9]*\)$/\1/p'  simple_text_file`.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the file is called vars.txt

```
sed -n 's/^VAR2=\(.*\)/\1/p' < vars.txt
```

You can use the value elsewhere like this using single back quotes

```
echo VAR2=`sed -n 's/^VAR2=\(.*\)/\1/p' < txt`
```

Comment: `sed -n 's/^VERSION=\(.*\)/\1/p' < vars.txt`

Comment: I don't understand what is written in these single quotes. What are they called and what is a good tutorial to learn this?

Comment: @AnimeshKumar that is the [sed s command which follows this syntax pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) and includes [use of regex](https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex): `s/regexp/replacement/`

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way might be to use `source` or simply `.` to read and execute the file. This would work with your example, because there are no spaces in the variable values. Otherwise you need to use grep + cut or awk, as stated in other answers.

```
. /path/to/your/file
echo $VAR2
```

[edit]
As stated by dawg, this would make the other variables available in your script too, and possibly overwrite existing variables.

Comment: He may not want the value of the other items set. `source` file will set all the variables to values in the file...

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
VAR1=100
VAR2=5
VAR3=0
VAR4=99
```

You can use awk:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk -F= '/^VAR2/ { print $2 }'
5
```

Or grep and cut:

```
$ echo "$txt"  | egrep '^VAR2=\d+' | cut -d = -f 2
5
```

On Bash, you can insert the value of those assignments into the current shell using [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)) and filter the lines you wish to use. In this case, only the line `VAR2=5` will be used. You need to write that to a file and then source that file:

```
$ echo "$txt"  | grep '^VAR2' > tmp && source tmp && rm tmp
$ echo "$VAR2"
5
```

Or use process substitution to eliminate the `tmp` file. You can use either `grep` or `awk` here:

```
$ source <(awk '/^VAR2/{print}' <<< "$txt")
$ echo "$VAR2"
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume this as your txt file, named test.txt

```
VAR2 = 5
VAR3 = 0
VAR4 = 99
```

you can `cat test.txt | grep 'VAR2' | awk '{printf $3}'`

and then your output will be: `5`

Here, `cat test.txt` will display the content of test.txt in your terminal,`grep 'VAR2'` will list lines containing 'VAR2' and `awk '{printf $3}'` will print the value of the variable

Comment: That doesn't work. Did you test this? Where? How?

Comment: I guess i have mistaken. Let me correct that, and thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Sorry, the remaining downvote is not mine, I cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For the files as described, you can just source the file as bash script which will run it's content and update you workspace environment with it. For example:

```
source file.txt
echo $VAR2
```