# how to read a variable from text file and assign that value to other variable using shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I have a huge text file which consists of various variables and other data. I have to search for a string "User_Name" and get its value(*name*, after = ). name after = is always "quoted"

I have one shell script which uses this text file data. At one point(line) in code it has to take the User_Name value.

Also, in the script "source" was not executed. because of some permissions rights I cannot add that command. I am seeing shell script for the first time, very new to shell language .

I have tried

```
User_Name = "$User_Name"
```

Comment: Use `awk` with `=` as field separator

Comment: The thing you've posted as an attempt in your question looks like an incorrect variable assignment, and doesn't make any reference to the "huge text file". What have you tried that attempts to solve the problem you've expressed in your question? Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: You need different solutions when you have different formats in the text file, like `user=string with spaces`, `user="quoted"` , `user=somethingWithAnEqualSign=Inside`,  `not_a_user=invalid` and `user = valueWithSpacesBeforeTheEqual`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296827/extracting-a-variables-value-from-text-file-using-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`User_Name=$(cat yourfileLocation | grep User_Name | cut -d = -f 2)`

You can try directly from console like this:

`User_Name=$(cat yourfileLocation | grep User_Name | cut -d = -f 2) | echo $User_Name`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not expected to "source" this file in at the top of your shell script so all variables are available without having to assign them? Think of it like reading in a library file that gets inserted at the top of your script.  Something to think about.

```
# Start of your script
. /path/to/your/variable/file  

echo "$User_Name"
```