# How to Make Use of Kubernetes Secrets in Bash Script

Tags: bash, kubernetes, sh

I have a secret stored in the Kubernetes pod which can be accessible by the following command.

```
kubectl exec -it pod_name -- printenv | grep SFTP_PASSWORD
```

which will provide the output as

```
SFTP_PASSWORD=password
```

I am accessing this secret in the bash script.

```
sftp_password=$(kubectl exec -it pod_name -- printenv | grep SFTP_PASSWORD)
```

But the issue I am facing is the above command will return both key-value pairs instead of value.

Comment: This might help: `echo "SFTP_PASSWORD=password" | sed 's/^SFTP_PASSWORD=//'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extracting a variable's value from text file using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296827/extracting-a-variables-value-from-text-file-using-bash)

Answer (score 1):

If it's an environment variable, you can just use ordinary Bourne shell [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) syntax:

```
kubectl exec pod_name -- sh -c 'echo $SFTP_PASSWORD'
```

Note the single quotes, to prevent the local shell from expanding the parameter; the `sh -c` wrapper so that a remote shell will be started to do the parameter expansion; and in this non-interactive use the `-it` options are unnecessary.

It's possible your cluster administrator prohibits `kubectl exec`, to prevent copying secret values out of the cluster in exactly this way.  This also avoids the non-standard `printenv` tool (it is part of GNU Coreutils and not the POSIX spec, so Alpine-based images may not have it).