# Read variable from file for usage in GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab

Given the following very simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` pipeline:

```yaml
---
variables:
  KEYCLOAK_VERSION: 20.0.1 # this should be populated from reading a file from the repo...

stages:
  - test

build:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "$KEYCLOAK_VERSION"
```

As you might see, this simply outputs the value of `KEYCLOAK_VERSION` defined in the `variables` section.

Now, the Git repository contains a `env.properties` file with `KEYCLOAK_VERSION=20.0.1` as content. How would I read the variable from that file and use it in the GitLab pipeline?

The documentation mentions `import` but this seems to be using YAML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read variables from a file you can use the `source` or `.` command.

```
script:
  - source env.properties
  - echo $KEYCLOAK_VERSION
```

**Attention:**
One reason why you might not want to do it this way is because whatever is in `env.properties` will be run in your shell, such as `rm -rf /`, which could be very dangerous.

Maybe you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296827/extracting-a-variables-value-from-text-file-using-bash) for some other solutions.